# Linking Symfony2 with Solr

Tags: php, symfony, solr

It's clear, how to plug Solr in Symfony2 framework? I found some resources out there but they're totally unclear or incomplete. There supposed to be a Symfony2 bundle named [NelmioSolariumBundle](http://knpbundles.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle) but can't get it well, poor documentation. 
If you have done this operation, please give us the *How-to* answer in few *Get-started* steps, or any good straightforward documentation/tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the source code for knpbundles.com (https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpBundles), it is a Symfony2 project which integrates Solr quite efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solr can be easily connected through it's REST interface, so if you have an easy use case, you might only have to use a PHP library that can talk to solr.

I use [this](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) library hosted on google code. Also I'm working on a solr bundle wich provides a convenient way of indexing doctrine entities, it can be found [here](https://github.com/roomthirteen/Room13SolrBundle) but it's also work in progress and almost no documentation....

The functionality so far is limited to index entities by cli and doing standard search. I'm currently using it in another bundle to index a geo database and providing an autocomplete form type for locations, you could check out the code for figure out the usage [here](https://github.com/roomthirteen/Room13GeoBundle)...

If my bundle is not of any help, you might get an idea of how to create your own implementation.

Comment: Using a Solr Client was in my mind before asking the question, and I read about Solr-php-client, so, I'm not sure if your question really replies to the question, but, anyway it might help other looking for answer for the same question. In that case, it may be an answer. I will suggest also **Solarium** as another Solr Client which I'm actually using and I found it easier and more straightforward than Sol-php-client.